# How to convert an extensive form game to strategic form when nature is involved at lower nodes

Tags: game-theory, economics

Posting this here and hoping that someone has come across it since I couldn't find an example anywhere online that looks similar.

I tried to find out how to convert this to strategic or normal form (which is the task I am supposed to do) but I am not completely sure on how I would do this considering that nature is present at a lower node.

My best guess so far is to include the part with nature and the probability of $1/2$ like this:

```
     (a,a)     (a,b)     (b,a)     (b,b)
A  (1.5,3.5) (1.5,3.5) (1.5,3.5) (1.5,3.5)
```

before continuing with the usual. I tried to find a similar example online, but whenever nature is involved, it is introduced at the root not as a leaf node leading to immediate payoffs. Since I cannot find an example online of this case, I do not know what is convention in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Game tree with nature at lower node]

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with Nature is correct: replace the terminal subgame where Nature plays with expected payoffs.

Be careful elsewhere, however: since Player 2 has an information set, she cannot tell apart $a$ from $b$ at different nodes, so her strategies are simply $a$ and $b$.